# Selecting descendants with certain classes that are beneath an element

Tags: css

In css I know you can select elements beneath their parent with the `>` selector:

```css
#myDiv > p {
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Is it possible to do the same for elements with a certain set of *classes* beneath that element, eg:

```css
#myDiv > .classA .classB {
  line-height: 1;
}
```

So that any child element with classes `.classA .classB` will get the treatment?

I've tried this and it doesn't seem to be working, and am not sure if I'm going down the right path or if I'm close.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of CSS that you have to repeat your self by doing

```
#myDiv > .classA, #myDiv > .classB
```

as your selector. Most CSS preprocessors can make this less of a challenge to keep things DRY.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can - but you have to follow the rules. A space character is also a descendant selector, and that's not what you want. If you want to select all descendants that have both classes, try:

```
#myDiv > .classA.classB {
  line-height: 1;
}
```